# ¿Cómo posicionar la rama master en el commit mas reciente?

Tags: git

El caso es el siguiente:

- Tengo un repositorio remoto al que se suben todos los cambios.
- Tengo un servidor, donde se reciben los cambios y actualizaciones del repositorio remoto.

Hasta aquí todo normal.

Ahora bien, cuando en el servidor se ejecuta `git pull origin master` trae los cambios sin problemas, pero me deja la rama *master* en un estado anterior de la actualización.

Ejemplo del log:

```
  *   985d0f0b (HEAD, tag: 1.3.1, origin/master) Merge branch 'name-branch'
  |\
  | * e9cb9ca9 ...
  | * ...
  |/
  *   49ceaa65 (tag: 1.3.0) Merge branch 'name-branch-1.3.0'
  |\
  | * 4051d017 ...
  | * 441d058b ...
  |/
  | * af735db0 ...
  * 57cce37a (tag: 1.2.0, master) Merge branch 'name-branch-1.2.0'
```

- Como se puede ver la rama *master* está con el *tag 1.2.0*.
- El *HEAD* lo muevo al *tag 1.3.1* con `git checkout 1.3.1`

La pregunta es igual al título:

**¿Cómo posicionar la rama master en el commit mas reciente?**

Debería quedar así:

```
  *   985d0f0b (HEAD, tag: 1.3.1, master, origin/master) Merge branch 'name-branch'
  |\
  | * e9cb9ca9 ...
  | * ...
  |/
  *   49ceaa65 (tag: 1.3.0) Merge branch 'name-branch-1.3.0'
  |\
  | * 4051d017 ...
  | * 441d058b ...
  |/
  | * af735db0 ...
  * 57cce37a (tag: 1.2.0) Merge branch 'name-branch-1.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando para resetear la rama master y que suba con la origin/master es:

```
git checkout -B master origin/master -f
```